# Creating button listeners for multiple Layouts .xml - Android

Tags: layout, program-entry-point, listeners

This is my NetABC java file in my project. Here I define multiple listeners for buttons in my main.xml layout. Everyone of those listeners work fine.

When I push the StatusButton (defined few scrolls down), it takes me to my second layout: status.xml.
In status.xml I have a few buttons. I would like to create listeners for them in NetABC.java aswell. Here's the problem:
Whenever I make listeners in NetABC.java for buttons in main.xml, everthing works perfectly well. The second I create a listener for a button which is not residing in main.xml layout, but insted, let's say status.xml layout I get an error when trying to simulate on AVD.

The last listener is an example of a button not residing in main.xml but in status.xml.
It's suppose to work as a back button, which takes me back from status.xml to main.xml.
I define it the same way as any other button listener I have defined. By using the R.id.button etc.

Any chance anyone would know why a listener defined for a button not in main.xml creates an error? Any help much appreciated.

```
package com.netabc;

import com.netabc.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;

public class NetABC extends Activity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

            //TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(    .IPText1);
            //myTextView.setText(ip);

            // Sett Klikk Lytter SSID Knapp
            Button SSIDButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SSIDButton);
            SSIDButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }        
            });

            // Sett Klikk Lytter IP Knapp
            Button IPButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.IPButton);
            IPButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }        
            });

            // Sett Klikk Lytter Subnetmaske Knapp
            Button SubnetmaskeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubnetmaskeButton);
            SubnetmaskeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }        
            });

            // Sett Klikk Lytter Default Gateway Knapp
            Button DefaultGatewayButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DefaultGatewayButton);
            DefaultGatewayButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }        
            });

            // Sett Klikk Lytter Nettverk Status Knapp
            Button StatusButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Nettverk_StatusButton);
            StatusButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.status);
                }        
            });

            // Sett Klikk Lytter Nettverk Ekstra Knapp
            Button EkstraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Nettverk_EkstraButton);
            EkstraButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.ekstra);
                }        
            });

            //Sett Klikk Lytter Back Knapp
            Button BackButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Signal_StyrkeButton);
            BackButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                }        
            }); 

    };
}
```